Problems with width="100%" of iFrame
I have the following iFrame:
<iframe id="inlineFrameExample" title="Inline Frame Example" frameborder="0" src="https://www.bla-bla.de/folder/subfolder/application/" height="100%" width="100%" class="no-print" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;">

The problem is now that I get a website with a horizontal scrollbar.
How can I configure the iframe, that it fits exactly the with of my screen?
I tried to remove the
width="100%" 

I also tried to remove the
width:100%;

in
style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;

Many thanks for your answers.

the website was tested with firefox

Adding further details to the question should be done through [edit] and not as a comment. The comment section is about asking about clarifications(either the question by others, or about other comments).

This link attempts to redirect. Redirection blocked, Remove the basic margin that body has. html, body{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }

A width of 100% on a child will result on its width having the same width as its parent, that might however result in an overflow in the parent container depending on what is set for its padding, margin and other css properties.

It’s because the <body> element has a default margin (which acts like padding does on other element types). Just set this margin to zero and you’ll be sweet.


body {
  margin: 0;
}

iframe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
<iframe src="https://www.bla-bla.de/folder/subfolder/application/" frameborder="0">



Alternatively, you could set top: 0 and left: 0 on the <iframe>.

Thanks for the info: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to change the body tag. The layout of the parent webseite of the iframe is fixed. I'm only responsible for the iframe.

found a solution that works, but I don't know if it is the "best" solution. I removed "position:absolute" and added "scrolling='no'". Then I changed % to vw for width and height.
